# How to escape quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, echo

I have that code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#two').html('<img src=\'http://willstern.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/jquerylogo2.png\' />');return false;">Add an Img</a>
```

and i don't know how to place it here `echo ' code ' ;`

Comment: What language you need to be more specific.

Comment: Your question should be "How to escape quotes in PHP?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work (tested)

```
<?php 

  echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"$('#two').html('<img src=\'http://willstern.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/jquerylogo2.png\' />');return false;\">Add an Img</a>";

?>
```

To escape single or double quotes in php you add a backslash just before `\'` `\"` [see the documentation.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Ah yes and the same goes for jQuery [see the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Quoting)

As you are using jQuery I would recommend that you separate your JS from your HTML a little, you could write the same code like this.

```
<a href="#" class="add_an_image">Add an Image</a>

<script>

  $('.add_an_image').click(function(){

    $('#two').html('<img src="http://willstern.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/jquerylogo2.png" />');
    return false;

  });

</script>
```

Comment: This will produce error in the js part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$code = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"$('#two').html('<img src=\'http://willstern.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/jquerylogo2.png\' />');return false;\">Add an Img</a>";

echo $code;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"$('#two').html('<img src=\'http://willstern.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/jquerylogo2.png\' />');return false;\">Add an Img</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax:

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
<a href="#" onclick="$('#two').html('<img src=\'http://willstern.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/jquerylogo2.png\' />');return false;">Add an Img</a>
EOD;
echo $str;
```